# Any way to embed Pygame in webpages?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a Pygame game, and I was wondering if there was any way to embed it into a webpage to make it easily playable, or if there is a games website that accepts Pygame games.

EDIT: I am now using Unity and am not after the answer anymore, but please answer if you want as it could help others.

Answer (score 7):

You could look at [Skulpt.org](http://www.skulpt.org) which provides a completely brower-based implementation of PyGame. However I do not know what external APIs PyGame uses and which are supported by Skulpt.

Edit: it seems Skulpt also has [WebGL bindings](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/1013082/im-looking-for-a-team-to-create-100-browser-based-python-interpreter) so this should be very possible!

Comment: I have tried several options.

Trinket.io didn't work well to me since it is cropping the game screen.
itch.io requires a downloadable file which I didn't have
I tried to use http://www.skulpt.org/, but it didn't even open.
So I ended up using replit.com, since this was the only site that didn't crop the game and could host pygame app in browser

Answer (score 0):

While poking around looking for PyGame GUI toolkits I came across these two libraries:
PyJ2D: http://gatc.ca/projects/pyj2d/
PyJSDL: http://gatc.ca/projects/pyjsdl/

The both seem to allow the execution of PyGame scripts in a browser, the first through Jython and a Java applet and the second through Javascript and HTML5.

I've never used either but they seem to be what you are after.